# Elasticsearch error client http traffic, closing connection

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, couchdb

I am using ElasticSearch version 1.4.0, nodejs version v0.8.12, Java version 1.8, CouchDB version 1.1.1.

My requirement is to create indexes for CouchDB databases in ElasticSearch using nodejs.

CouchDB has `employee_details` db. For this I want to create indexes in ElasticSearch using nodejs.
My actual code is:

```
var employeeData={
    "type" : "couchdb",
    "couchdb" : {
      "host" : couch,
      "port" : port,
      "db" :"employee_details"
      "filter" : null
    },
    "index" :{
      "index" : "masters_asset",
      "type" : "masters_asset",
      "bulk_size" : "100",
      "bulk_timeout" : "10ms"
    }  
};

var mastersAssetName= "masters_asset";
elasticSearchClient.createOrModifyTwitterRiver(employeeData, employeeName)
  .on('data', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
     callback(JSON.parse(data));
  })
  .on('error', function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      callback(null);
  }).exec();
```

When I run this code from nodejs, I am getting the error:

```
***{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }***
```

and in Elasticsearch I am getting this exception:

```
***[2014-11-21 16:06:57,370][WARN ][http.netty               ] [Aginar] Caught exception while handling client http traffic, closing connection [id: 0x75290d26, /10.50.7.109:55643 :> /10.50.7.109:9210]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:97)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:191)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.cleanup(ReplayingDecoder.java:554)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelDisconnected(FrameDecoder.java:365)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:396)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:360)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:81)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:779)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:54)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:784)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.closeRequested(SimpleChannelHandler.java:334)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleDownstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:260)
  at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.handleDownstream(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:105)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:582)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.close(Channels.java:812)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:197)
  at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.NettyHttpServerTransport.exceptionCaught(NettyHttpServerTransport.java:335)
  at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.HttpRequestHandler.exceptionCaught(HttpRequestHandler.java:70)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.exceptionCaught(SimpleChannelHandler.java:156)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:130)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.exceptionCaught(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:153)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.exceptionCaught(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:153)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.exceptionCaught(FrameDecoder.java:377)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:525)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.AbstractChannelSink.exceptionCaught(AbstractChannelSink.java:48)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.notifyHandlerException(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:658)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:566)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
  at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)***
```

Comment: How did you instantiate elasticSearchClient ? Make sure you are using http.  If the client is configured to use https you see that error. It could be other errors but this is the first thing I would check

Answer (score 1):

Use port 9300 (transport TCP port) while connecting to `elasticsearch`.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! To make your answer more useful, you should include instructions or code examples of *how* to use the port you recommend.